# Swiftui Google Maps user marker in top left corner issue

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, swiftui

When I open the map, the user's marker is in the upper left corner, instead of being in the center, just when I click show my position button, the camera becomes so that the user marker is in the upper left corner again. What is the problem ? how do i show the user marker in the center of the map. [image: map screen]

My LocationManager class:

```
class LocationManager: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    
    // Singleton instance
    public static let shared : LocationManager = {
        return LocationManager()
    }()
    
    private let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    
    @Published var location: CLLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    
        location = locationManager.location  ?? CLLocation(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
    }
    
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let currentLocation = locations.last else { return }
        self.location = currentLocation
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            locationManager.requestLocation()
            location = locationManager.location ?? CLLocation(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Swift.Error) {
        appLog.debug(error)
    }
}
```

MapView:

```
struct GoogleMapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var coordinates: [Coordinate]
    
    let zoom: Float = 15.0
    var showMyLocationButton = true
    var mapBoundsCallback: ([Double], [Double]) -> ()
    
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    private var mapView: GMSMapView?
    
    init(coordinates: Binding<[Coordinate]>,
         zoom: Float = 15.0,
         showMyLocationButton: Bool = true,
         mapBoundsCallback: @escaping ([Double], [Double]) -> ()) {
        
        self.showMyLocationButton = showMyLocationButton
        self.mapBoundsCallback = mapBoundsCallback
        _coordinates = coordinates
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Self.Context) -> GMSMapView {
        let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withTarget: LocationManager.shared.location.coordinate , zoom: zoom)
        let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
        mapView.animate(to: camera)
        mapView.delegate = context.coordinator
        mapView.settings.compassButton = true
        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.settings.myLocationButton = showMyLocationButton
        return mapView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, context: Context) {
        mapView.clear()
        
        if coordinates.isEmpty {
            return
        }
        
        let path = GMSMutablePath()
        var bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds()
        
        for coordinate in coordinates {
            if let lat = coordinate.coordinates?[0], let lng = coordinate.coordinates?[1] {
                let locationCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(lat, lng)
                path.add(locationCoordinate)
                bounds = bounds.includingCoordinate(locationCoordinate)
            }
        }
        
        let rectangle = GMSPolyline(path: path)
        rectangle.strokeColor = Theme.colorDarkGrey.uiColor()
        rectangle.strokeWidth = 2.0
        rectangle.map = mapView
        
        mapView.animate(with: GMSCameraUpdate.fit(bounds))
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator { ne, sw in
            mapBoundsCallback(ne, sw)
        }
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, GMSMapViewDelegate {
        
        var cameraPositionCallback: ([Double], [Double]) -> ()
        
        init(cameraPositionCallback: @escaping ([Double], [Double]) -> ()) {
            self.cameraPositionCallback = cameraPositionCallback
        }
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
            let farRight = mapView.projection.visibleRegion().farRight
            let nearLeft = mapView.projection.visibleRegion().nearLeft
            let ne: [Double] = [Double(farRight.latitude), Double(farRight.longitude)]
            let sw: [Double] = [Double(nearLeft.latitude), Double(nearLeft.longitude)]
            cameraPositionCallback(ne, sw)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that issue happens only on views opens by `NavigationLink`. If store `GMSMapView()` on some root ViewModel, present `GoogleMapView` on some first view as first layer, then you can pass `GMSMapView()` to other views, build `GoogleMapView` and present it. For me such solution helps...